# How to summarize a dataframe in a matrix form based on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have:

```
Column A    Column B    Column C
   A_1        B_1         0
   A_1        B_2         1
   A_2        B_3         3
   A_2        B_5         2
```

I would like to get this:

```
       B_1   B_2  B_3  B_5
A_1     0     1   nan  nan
A_2    nan   nan   3    2
```

My idea is to get the unique values of Column A and Column B, recreate a new dataframe based on that and fill in the blanks through 2 for loops. Is there a better way to do this using Pandas? My method takes too long with large dataframe.

Comment: Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1

```
df.set_index(['Column A','Column B'])['Column c'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
Column B  B_1  B_2  B_3  B_5
Column A                    
A_1       0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
A_2       NaN  NaN  3.0  2.0
```

## Option 2

```
pd.crosstab(df['Column A'],df['Column B'],df['Column C'],aggfunc='sum')
```

## Option 3

```
df.pivot_table('Column C','Column A','Column B','sum')
```

## Option 4

```
df.pivot('Column A','Column B','Column C')
```